# Is there a way to get the Innotab Learning Lodge Navigator software working?

Tags: wine

I bought my daughter an [innotab](http://www.vtechkids.com/brands/brand_view/innotab) for christmas, is there any way to get the learning lodge navigator working in WINE since its not compatable with linux?

I mean I need to be able to plug her innotab into

Comment: I have successfully gotten the Learning Lodge software to run, but cannot manually mount the InnoTab device.
@Amanda- did you actually get the device to mount?

Answer (score 2):

It runs in Wine. It may take you a try or two to get it past the installation. Remember to install Flash for Win XP, the ¨other browsers¨ version.

Now the only problem is getting it to recognize the USB connection. I haven't figured that out yet, not that I've been trying that long.

Comment: its very very difficult to get wine to detect directly USB devices.  The best you would achieve through wine is to access folders mounted via nautilus - i.e. mount a media device and you will be able to browse via the z: drive mapping in a wine/windows app (folder is usually mounted in /media)

Answer (score 0):

It is frustrating to have these sort of compatibility problems, and wine can sometimes be hard to get working. You might want to try running windows in Virtualbox (or dual booting).

I would take the time to (politely) raise your problems with the innotab manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

it is running in an OTHER browser so you need to download the flash player for other browsers, after hours of frustration it is actually in vtech's frequently asked questions grrr!! working away fine now. hope that helps